# UITextField cursor not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield

I have a scenario where I present UITextFields to user one by one in my iOS app written in swift. How I have achieved this is by using collection view and having a cell that has a textfield in it. I want the cells to automatically show keyboard for textfield so I added the code to make the textfield become first responder. Now the problem is when the collection view loads, the keyboard appears but the textfield is not editable. I have no clue what is happening here. Here I am attaching the code as well.

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MortgageFormCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MortgageFormCell
            
            let m = formMenu[indexPath.item]
            cell.textField.tag = m.tag // every textField has separate tag
            let t = m.title
            let p = m.placeholder
            cell.subtitleLabel.text = m.subtitle

            cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
            
            cell.titleLabel.text = t
            cell.textField.placeholder = p
            cell.textField.delegate = nil
            cell.textField.keyboardType = .decimalPad
            cell.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
return cell
```

Help me understand what is going wrong and how can I fix it.

Comment: I think your structure and way are wrong. This line will create problem inside cell for method ``` cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()```